# How to disable the system context menu in Electron custom titlebar?

Tags: electron

I am using an Electron frameless window with a custom titlebar, but there is a context menu when right clicking on it. How can I disable showing this menu?

[image]

this is electron version：

```
"electron": "^11.3.0",
```

and this is electron start program:main.js，but system-context-menu not working here after app start.

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

let mainWindow;
function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
    frame: false,
    useContentSize: true,
    hasShadow: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
    },
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL(
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
      ? 'http://localhost:5000'
      : url.format({
          pathname: path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html'),
          protocol: 'file:',
          slashes: true,
        })
  );

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  }

  mainWindow.on('system-context-menu', (event, _point) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  });
}

const gotTheLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock();
if (!gotTheLock) {
  app.quit();
} else {
  app.on('second-instance', (event, commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
    if (mainWindow) {
      if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) mainWindow.restore();
      mainWindow.focus();
    }
  });

  app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

  app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
      app.quit();
    }
  });

  // just work in macOS
  // https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#%E4%BA%8B%E4%BB%B6-activate-macos
  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, you should be able to intercept the [`system-context-menu`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-system-context-menu-windows) event of the `BrowserWindow` and cancel it.

```
mainWindow.on("system-context-menu", (event, _point) => {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This behavior was added in Electron 11 in [this PR](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/25795).

**Edit:** this event actually doesn't fire for frameless windows, because of [this Electron bug](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/26726). It will need to be fixed before my solution works. I'm not aware of any workaround to this.

Comment: which Electron version are you on? can you show some code?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I added my code to the above question

Comment: woops - the event actually doesn't fire because of an [Electron bug](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/26726). It will need to be fixed before my solution works...

Comment: as far as I know, no. FWIW this is only an issue for frameless windows. But you can always disable items making the window not closable/minimazable/etc

Comment: thank you all the same, I may wait this [Electron bug](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/26726) to be solved in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Electron still not fix this bug, I'm so tired that Electron have lots of bug on windows .

and it works , try it :

```
  const WM_INITMENU = 0x0116;
  const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([]);

  win.hookWindowMessage(WM_INITMENU, () => {
    win.setEnabled(false);
    win.setEnabled(true);
    menu.popup();
  });
```

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/24893#issuecomment-1109262719

Answer (score 0):

Base on Jour answer
Do following codes it works on my side,key points are two ( 0x0116 and make buildFormTemplate as null),of course, Meanwhile, you wanna have your own right_click menu, you can follow electron doc to develop,

```
 const WM_INITMENU = 0x0116
 const right_menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([])
    mainWindow.hookWindowMessage(WM_INITMENU, () => {
    mainWindow.setEnabled(false)
    mainWindow.setEnabled(true)
])
```

Sample about own menu

```
 const WM_INITMENU = 0x0116
 const right_menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([{"label":"About",...,function(){}},{"label":"Exit",...,function(){}}])
        mainWindow.hookWindowMessage(WM_INITMENU, () => {
        mainWindow.setEnabled(false)
        mainWindow.setEnabled(true)
        right_menu.popup()
    ])
```